# Select Only first row from the join result

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure where i am using below two tables

```
Ticket Nav Group(Table) - 

Column:

Ticket Type ID
Ticket Nav Group Id 

Ticket Sorting(Table) - 

Column :

Ticket TypeId,
Nav GroupId,
Priority
```

I did inner join between these tables. using ticket type Id

since the ticket type id and Navgroup Id and Priority is different, I have found some duplicate row .

Now my requirement is i need to select only the first matching row from this result for each ticket type Id .

Also I need to display ticket type Id and Priority in the result

Comment: Is it DISTINCT you're asking for?

Comment: try using row_number,partition.google it.learn

Comment: use top 1 * in select query will get you first row of your result simple

Comment: any you try with DISTINCT keyword whats result you aspected

Comment: we cant use Distinct because the Proirity and Ticket type Id value are different. Also we cant use Top 1 * because we need to get the first row of each ticket type Id

Comment: Any try with row_number() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple `Ticket TypeId` in second table, you can join like this:

```
Select 
    a.[Ticket Type ID], a.[Ticket Nav Group Id], b.[Priority]
FROM 
    [Ticket Nav Group] a
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT [Ticket TypeId], MAX([Priority]) 
            FROM [Ticket Sorting]
            GROUP BY [Ticket TypeId]
        ) b 
        ON b.[Ticket TypeId] = a.[Ticket Type ID]
```

and If I understand right, I think you have a table design issue.

Answer (score 0):

Although you are after a solution for your query, I think you should go back and reassess your DB structure.

With this structure:

```
Ticket Nav Group(Table) - 
{
Ticket TypeID
Ticket NavGroup Id 
}

Ticket Sorting(Table) - 
{
Ticket TypeId,
Nav GroupId,
Priority
}
```

You should only have the second table. Otherwise you are duplicating data.

Please give more details about your data base structure. Also be more clear in your question and structure. Is TypeId a foreign key from a Type table? Why did you spelled it in two words in the first table and together in the second table.

Comment: We don't have anything like foreign key. The column name is TicketTypeId only... i just spelled it as two diff words for better readability.

Comment: If you only need to display ticket type Id and Priority in the result. Lets consider you want to show the one with the highest priority:

 select typeid, max(agreagator)
 [from, joins and conditions here]
 group by typeid